# Angular router resolve results in an unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use Angular's routing to resolve the necessary objects for the controller scope. I have  read a few tutorials on how to do this but I still get an `Unknown Provider` error. The issue seems to be with `project` being injected into `ProjectDetailCtrl`.

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config( function ($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    ...
    .when('/project/:projectId', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/_project_detail.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            project: function ($route, MyService) {
                return MyService.get('projects/', $route.current.params.projectId).then(function(data) {
                    console.log('VERIFY DATA: ', data);
                    return data;
                });
            }
        }
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', function ($scope, project) {
    $scope.project = project;
}
```

### Edit

**services.js**

```
.factory('MyService', function ($http, $q) {

var MyService = {
    ...
    get: function (items_url, objId) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', 
            url: api_url + items_url + objId}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.reject(status);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    },
```

### Edit 2

The issue is apparently not with the Service method, as this also produces the error:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config( function ($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    ...
    .when('/project/:projectId', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/_project_detail.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            project: {title: 'foo'}
        }
     });
})
```

I can verify my resolve function is being returned properly, but Angular still complains that `project` is unidentified. What is this issue here? I have tried making my controllers into a module and passing that to the myApp module, but I still get the same `Unidentified Provider` issue for `project`.

*Note:* I am using Angular 1.2.9.

### Edit 3: solution

So the issue was this line in my template:

```
<!-- WRONG: <div ng-controller="ProjectDetailCtrl">-->
<div>

  <h2 ng-show="project">Project: <strong>{{ project.title }}</strong></h2>

</div>
```

Apparently the `ng-controller` directive cannot be use with resolve.

Comment: What is exact error? ```Unidentified Provider projectProvider```?

Comment: `Unknown Provider error in component $injector`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS, resolve and unknown provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846466/angularjs-resolve-and-unknown-provider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) as a dependency for your module. Thats why $routeProvider and $route service are undefined.

**Update**:

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xrqtw/1/) example. Problem was in `ng-controller` directive

Comment: Sorry - I had just taken out those dependencies to make the question more precise. In my code `ngRoute` is there - issue remains.

Comment: @DarwinTech See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2619). Don't you use ```ng-controller``` directive?

Comment: @DarwinTech Updated answer with fiddle.

Comment: I don't think so. I am using the `ng-controller` directive in my template.

Comment: @DarwinTech The problem is that you must **not** use this directive, to resolve work properly.

Comment: Ahh right. Yes - I just discovered this. So if I use `routes` then I shouldn't use the `ng-controller` directive? Why exactly is this? I didn't find it documented very well.

Comment: @DarwinTech It is not documented. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849050/simple-angular-routeprovider-resolve-test-what-is-wrong-with-this-code) post as a proof.

Comment: Hmmm. So is the issue because `ProjectDetailCrtl` is already registered from the template?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the MyService.get, which is a promise, and then within the result of the promise, you're returning the data.... but to what?

You want to return the promise, but not the original promise... so you create your own promise using `$q`, and Angular will wait and resolve it for you before loading your route.

```
project: function ($route, MyService) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            MyService.get('projects/', $route.current.params.projectId).then(function(data) {
                console.log('VERIFY DATA: ', data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Or, assuming MyService.get returns a promise, you should be able to just do

```
 project: function ($route, MyService) {
            return MyService.get('projects/', $route.current.params.projectId);
        }
```

And obviously inject `$q` into config

Comment: hmmm. I already return the deferred promise from my Service, though I should have included that code before. Please see my edits.

Comment: yes, but you're handling it by doing `then` which basically says we're done with the promise. See my second edit. The promise needs to get returned to angular, not the data.

Comment: I see your point, and this may well need addressing too. However, this is not the issue here. If I switch out the Service method for a simple object, the error remains.

Comment: @JonathanRowny You are not correct. ```then``` method returns new promise. See [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L283)

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot that then returns a new promise for chaining. I guess that's why it might have worked. If that's not the problem them I'm not sure what it is.  Are you running any minifiers or anything? If you include the non-minified version of Angular you usually get better errors as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about better errors in the non-minified version of Angular. Switching that, I get the same issue but the error is slightly more verbose: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: projectProvider <- project`

Comment: hmm, maybe try defining the controller with the long (strict form)?

Comment: Yes - tried that, Still the same. For whatever reason it seems that project is not being registered as Provider. ??

Answer (score 0):

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846466/angularjs-resolve-and-unknown-provider), therefore it's a possible duplicate.

- The top answer points out usage of controllers within markup to have caused this.
- Search your codebase (`markup` or `templates` to be exact) for the term `ng-controller`.
- Verify if there is a matching controller, as in this case `ProjectDetailCtrl`
- Remove it from the markup

It solved the problem in my case.