# Unknown provider: productProvider <- product

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a strange problem with Angularjs i have an Unknown provider: productProvider <- product error in my Controller.

The product variable i am injecting is filled i can see this in the log.
In my module config i have the following code:

```
$routeProvider.when('/products/edit/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/static/templates/products/edit.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ProductsEditCtrl',
        resolve:{
            product:['productService', '$route', function(productService, $route){
                return productService.getById($route.current.params.id);
            }]
        }
    });
```

In my controller:

```
.controller('ProductsEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'productService', '$timeout', 'product', function ($scope, $location, productService, $timeout, product) {

    $scope.product = product;
```

Can anyone see what the problem can be here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849050/simple-angular-routeprovider-resolve-test-what-is-wrong-with-this-code

Comment: Pfff indeed i've set the Controller also in the view. Thanks lucuma!