# Why promise doesnt work as expected in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

In my AngularJS application on every request to change the page i run :

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        var user;
        $http.get('/api/Authentication/UserAuthenticated').then(function (data) {
        console.log("call");
         user = data.data;
       });   
      console.log("end of call");
    });
```

When i run application and test what is happening i see in console that "end of call" is returned before `console.log("call");` which means that user is not set. Which means that if i want to check if user is logged in on change of route user will be undefined.

How do i make Angular run-> http request and only then keep going?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with `promises`, but rather, `$http` making an asynchronous call.  Since the `get` call is async, `"end of call"` will always seen first.

Comment: For this kind of task you should use `resolve` property of the route configuration.

Comment: Can u give an example of how i can implement it with resolve? I can see i docs that resolve will make rute wait until all http requests are done

Comment: Please checkout my answer.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the question a bit. You can let the [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) resolve the `$http` promise:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");

app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl: "myTemplate.html",
    controller: "MyCtrl",
    resolve: {
      user: ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/api/Authentication/UserAuthenticated').success(function(data){
           deferred.resolve(data.data);
        }).error(function(error) {
           deferred.resolve(false);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
  });
}]);
```

If the code to fetch the user data is too complex, you could create a service for it, and inject that service in the `$routeProvider`'s `resolve` function.

In your controller, you just inject the promise (which will be resolved):

```
app.controller("MyCtrl",["$scope","user", function($scope, user) {
   if (!user) {
      alert("User not found");
   }
...
}]);
```

Comment: $scope.user = data.data; will be set to late, so location change will pass by before http will get response.

Comment: One last question ,how do i select user parameter on my route when i change location? in onlocationChangestart?

Comment: What do you mean by 'user parameter'. Does the $http request need a userid string (e.g. '12345') which is filled in via an input form?

Comment: I just want to show a popup message when user is false, and i try to check it in $locationChangeStart, but i cant get user parameter out from $route

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly. You'll notice in the error block a `resolve(false)`. In your controller you get `false` for `user`. Of course you will need to improve this.

Comment: You don't have to create a new deferred for the resolve, you can return the data from a success handler of the then method which will wrap the result in a new promise for you and reduce the amount of code required.  See: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/03/26/tips-for-javascript-promises.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use `async:false`. It is working for me

Try this code, instead of your code

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
$http({method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/Authentication/UserAuthenticated',                
            async: false
              }).success(function (data) {
            console.log("call");
            user = data.data;
             }
         console.log("end of call");   
 });
```

Comment: I didn't vote you down but I suspect it is because you are using a "hacky" solution to get around normal behavior.